# Problem when sending a local mail with Maildev in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, smtp, laravel-7

I'm stuck with a problem sending a local mail on the Maildev server from Laravel and I can't find the answer.
Here is the code of my .env file :

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

and here's the error:

```
Swift_TransportException
Cannot send a message without a sender address
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, the error message is exactly telling you what is wrong. You need to add an from-address. If you are sending local mails you can just put any string there and it is interpreted as a username. Since you have it configured to SMTP you should probably add an email address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says exactly what's wrong. You can't send emails without providing sender address. You need to provide account details like username, password and email address of that user.